# VMWare: guest machine internet working randomly

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have an issue with the internet in my VMWare guest machine working very randomly (mostly not working) and I am not sure what the issue might be.

Sometimes the internet works (this also includes possibility to ssh to the host), but most of the time it doesn't.

Restarting `networking` doesn't help, nor any `ifdown`/`ifup`'s. The only situation when it might start working is restarting the whole VM. And even then it starts working perhaps one time in 10.

The only potential issue I have noticed so far is that when it doesn't work, VM network adapters' MAC addresses are swapped - while if it works, they are as configured.

Details:

- host: OS X El Capitan 10.11.4 running VMWare Fusion 8.0.1
- guest: Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u2 x86_64 GNU/Linux

VMWare virtual machine network settings:

- Network Adapter 1 - NAT - static MAC address `00:50:56:38:CC:21`
- Network Adapter 2 - Host only - static MAC address `00:50:56:38:CC:22`

In my virtual machine `.vmx` configuration file I have this (related to the interfaces):

```
ethernet0.present = "TRUE"
ethernet0.connectionType = "nat"
ethernet0.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet0.addressType = "static"
ethernet0.linkStatePropagation.enable = "FALSE"
ethernet0.pciSlotNumber = "33"
ethernet0.address = "00:50:56:38:CC:21"
ethernet0.startConnected = "TRUE"
ethernet0.vnet = "vmnet2"
ethernet0.bsdName = "en0"
ethernet0.displayName = "Wi-Fi"
...
ethernet1.present = "TRUE"
ethernet1.connectionType = "hostonly"
ethernet1.virtualDev = "e1000"
ethernet1.wakeOnPcktRcv = "FALSE"
ethernet1.addressType = "static"
ethernet1.linkStatePropagation.enable = "FALSE"
ethernet1.pciSlotNumber = "37"
ethernet1.address = "00:50:56:38:CC:22"
ethernet1.startConnected = "TRUE"
```

Host `ifconfig`:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a0:99:9b:0b:bf:c5 
    inet6 fe80::a299:9bff:fe0b:bfc5%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
    inet 10.230.82.42 netmask 0xffffc000 broadcast 10.230.127.255
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
en1: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:ba:d6:30 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
en2: flags=963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX> mtu 1500
    options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 6a:00:01:ba:d6:31 
    media: autoselect <full-duplex>
    status: inactive
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether a2:99:9b:b0:3e:00 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
p2p0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
    ether 02:99:9b:0b:bf:c5 
    media: autoselect
    status: inactive
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1484
    ether 7a:81:75:a1:0f:87 
    inet6 fe80::7881:75ff:fea1:f87%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x9 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
vmnet1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01 
    inet 192.168.247.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.247.255
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08 
    inet 192.168.195.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.195.255
```

Guest `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.195.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.195.2

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.247.200
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Guest `ifconfig` (when internet works):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:21  
          inet addr:192.168.195.200  Bcast:192.168.195.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc21/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:470 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:461 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:74106 (72.3 KiB)  TX bytes:53650 (52.3 KiB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:22  
          inet addr:172.16.121.132  Bcast:172.16.121.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1648 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:578 (578.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:61 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:24465 (23.8 KiB)  TX bytes:24465 (23.8 KiB)
```

Guest `ifconfig` (when internet doesn't work):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:22  
          inet addr:192.168.195.200  Bcast:192.168.195.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc22/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:217 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2472 (2.4 KiB)  TX bytes:9398 (9.1 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:38:cc:21  
          inet addr:192.168.247.200  Bcast:192.168.247.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fe38:cc21/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3498 (3.4 KiB)  TX bytes:620 (620.0 B)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:219 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:42755 (41.7 KiB)  TX bytes:42755 (41.7 KiB)
```

Here I can see the only difference - the MAC addresses are the other way round, compared to how they are configured.

When internet works:

- from the guest, pinging all 192.168.195.* works fine (.200, .2 and .1)
- from the host, I can ping myself (.1) and the guest (.200), pinging .2 gives me 'Request timeout' error

When it doesn't work:

- from the guest I can ping myself (192.168.195.200), but pinging any other 192.168.195.* (.2 or .1) gives me 'Destinaton Host Unreachable' error. Same when pinging the internet (for example 8.8.4.4)
- from the host I can ping myself (192.168.195.1), but pinging any other 192.168.195.* (.2 or .200) gives me 'Request timeout' error.

Any idea why this might be happening, and what else I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have install VMWare guest tools on Debian? Maybe this is the similar problem like your https://communities.vmware.com/message/2350978#2350978 this is windows guest VM but the solution look like applicable in you case too. This is windows guest VM but the solution look like applicable in your case too. I mean last solution - Workaround (15 minutes)

Comment: Thanks stambata! Yes, I do have guest tools installed (and re-installed). I have also tried fully reinstalling the VMWare following https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1017838 Not really sure if the problem is similar, because in my case if it works after starting the VM, it doesn't stop working. The thing is that most of the time it doesn't work from the very start...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved now.

I tried the workaround described at https://communities.vmware.com/message/2350978#2350978 - generally creating a new VM using the existing VMDK virtual disk (which re-created all the external VM settings) - it worked flawlessly, even though being a little overkill.

Just in case I have kept the copy of the original problematic VM, and then, after getting [help from the VMWare employee](https://communities.vmware.com/message/2591161#2591088) - which suggested removing the NAT adapter settings (all `ethernet0.` entries) from the VM's `.vmx` configuration file, then removing the network adapter itself, and then re-adding it - everything started working perfectly.

Guess I just had some old settings in the `.vmx` file, from previous versions of VMWare, or old VM configurations...